# Force Mercurial (Hg) to add new files automatically

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm looking for the opposite mechanism to the `.ignore` file, which should add all files of a given pattern automatically, for example `*.tex` for any LaTeX documentation project or `*.def` for any file that was added by OASIS (an MS Access addin for version control).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`hg add` with no arguments will add all files not explicitly ignored. You can also use `hg commit --addremove` to add all unknown files (and remove all deleted files, i.e. `hg rm` any which `hg status` lists as '!') to do this automatically when committing.

Comment: With the alias `-A` for `--addremove` this can be abbreviated to `hg ci -A`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding files only happens when you run `hg add`. If you want to add all files matching a pattern, use the `--include` (`-I`) switch.